# Reading UTF Strings larger than UnsignedShort.MAX_VALUE in DataInputStream

Tags: java, utf-8, decoding

As far as I know, DataInputStream is the only way to deserialize strings using Modified-UTF8. Unfortunately, there is a limit on how large the String can be, since the length is an unsigned short.

The primary motivation for using Modified-UTF8 is that Java 8 no longer allows for 3-byte surrogates / 6-byte surrogate pairs, so the following code does not function properly (on Strings with those surrogates):

```
String surrogatePairs = "\uD83C\uDFE0\uD83C\uDF4E\uD83D\uDCA9";

// Serialization process using 3-byte surrogates

String deserialized = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
assertEquals(surrogatePairs, deserialized); // fails
```

This code, however, works properly:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(len + 2);
bb.putShort((short) len).put(nonNullValue, offset, len);

ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bb.array());
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

assertEquals(surrogatePairs, dis.readUTF()); // OK
```

The problem with this approach is that there is no restriction for how large the String can be, so if the length of the String exceeds that of an unsigned short, it will not work properly.

Is there an alternative method to deserializing Strings with 3-byte surrogates / 6-byte surrogate pairs? The data encoded is guarenteed to be UTF-8, if that addresses any concerns with a String being over Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2.

Comment: +1 I would consider copying the code from DataInputStream and handling any length you need.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yea I tried that and it worked fine. My issue was just the licensing. Maybe the Open JDK implementation will be fine.

Comment: Agreed. The code should be the same but just in case ....